# Mongo addfields returns collection not value

Tags: .net, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am try to do some math functions on 3 values from a left joined collected the values are in the right collection.

```
$AllBodies=Invoke-MdbcAggregate @(
    # filter bodies with arsenic
    @{ '$match' = @{
       'name' ='Gru Hypue KS-T d3-31 9 b a'
       'materials' = @{ '$elemMatch'=@{ 'material_name'="Arsenic" } }
    }}
    # list just the name, materials array and FK
    @{ '$project' = @{ 
       'system_id'=1;
       'name'=1;
       'materials'=1;
    }}
    # unwind the array, duplicates source record
    @{ '$unwind' = @{
       'path' = '$materials';
        'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays' = $false
    }}
    # now re-filter the for just the material arsenic/
    @{ '$match' = @{
       'materials.material_name' = 'Arsenic';
       'materials.share'         = @{ '$gte' = 2.7 }
    }}
    # sort the records by % arsenic descending
    @{ '$sort' = @{
       'materials.share' = -1
    }}
    # left join the systems collection
    @{ '$lookup' = @{
       'from'         = 'systems'
       'localField'   = 'system_id'
       'foreignField' = 'id'
       'as'           = 'systems'
    }}
    # add fields to work with later - more dev required
    @{ '$addFields' = @{
       'x' = '$systems.x'
       'y' = '$systems.y'
       'z' = '$systems.z'
       'systemname' = '$systems.name'
    }}
) -Collection $bodies
```

I am trying to bring the values up a level into the top document as I am having trouble with maths functions complaining about dot referenced fields.

In the top document I want d=sqr((x1-x2)2+(y1-y2)2+(z1-z2)2).

I am trying to do this during the query time rather than re-process the whole collection, there are 100,000's of entries (potentially)

The code is in PowerShell with .net driver, happy to have in .js though

Out put is as follows...

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                                                
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                                                
_id                            59cbf243ef32b7bbe22654b4                                                                                                                                                                             
name                           Gru Hypue KS-T d3-31 9 b a                                                                                                                                                                           
system_id                      3288878                                                                                                                                                                                              
materials                      {material_id, material_name, share}                                                                                                                                                                  
systems                        {{ "_id" : ObjectId("59cba528ef32b7bbe28a7640"), "id" : 3288878, "edsm_id" : 2749852, "name" : "Gru Hypue KS-T d3-31", "x" : -4990.84375, "y" : -935.71875, "z" : 13387.15625, "population" : 1000...
y                              {-935.71875}                                                                                                                                                                                         
systemname                     {Gru Hypue KS-T d3-31}                                                                                                                                                                               
z                              {13387.15625}                                                                                                                                                                                        
x                              {-4990.84375}
```

As you can see x,y,z are collections rather than values

TIA

Comment: Please share some sample input data and the desired output plus a proper question. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: sorry tried to be brief...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you will need to simply change your last stage into:

```
@{ '$addFields' = @{
   'x' = @{ '$arrayElemAt' = @( '$systems.x', 0 ) }
   'y' = @{ '$arrayElemAt' = @( '$systems.y', 0 ) }
   'z' = @{ '$arrayElemAt' = @( '$systems.z', 0 ) }
   'systemname' = '$systems.name'
}}
```

This will give you the first value of each array only.

Comment: They are not arrays they would be enclosed with [ ], they are collection { }.  I get error "Invoke-MdbcAggregate : Cannot bind parameter 'Pipeline' to the target. Exception setting "Pipeline": ".NET type System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock cannot be mapped to a BsonValue."
At line:2 char:33
+ $AllBodies=Invoke-MdbcAggregate @(
+                                 ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Invoke-MdbcAggregate], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterBindingFailed,Mdbc.Commands.InvokeAggregateCommand"

Comment: They are arrays, it's just the driver that displays them in a funny way. I fixed the above syntax into correct powershell (tested) so it should work properly now.